# On Google Drive, how do I download files?

Tags: google-drive

So I was uploading to Google Drive, and I found the lack of a download button on the home page. Where is the download button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highlight the file.

Open the overflow menu (three vertical dots).

Select "Download".

[image: overflow menu]

Or, if you install the Google Drive app on your PC, the file(s) will automatically sync to your hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you want to download all your files at once, use the [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) service.